# problems with differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

i have problems solving eq. 
$$ u + \log(u-1) = \log (x); \quad u= \frac{y}{x}$$
which comes from solving diff equation 
$$x \frac{dy}{dx} - y= x\frac{y-x}{y+x}$$
any hints?

thanks in advance

Comment: This can't be solved with elementary functions. This is the best you'll be able to do with elementary functions, honestly.

Comment: See the [Lambert W function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

Comment: the solution can expressed by the ProductLog

Comment: Your answer is great, thanks. I just wasn't familiar with Lambert's function before

Comment: Thanks!  The W function actually has fascinating properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have

$$u+\log(u-1)=\log x\implies (u-1)+\log(u-1)=\log(x/e)\tag 1$$

Now, we know that Lambert's $W$ function is defined as $z=W(z)e^{W(z)}$.

This can be rewritten as

$$\log z=W(z) +\log W(z).\tag 2$$

Letting $W(z)=u-1$ and $z=x/e$, $(2)$ becomes

$$\log (x/e)=(u-1)+\log (u-1)\tag 3$$

Comparing $(1)$ and $(3)$ reveals that

$$u=1+W(x/e)$$

and thus, we have

$$y(x)=x+xW(x/e)$$